# Select GPS coordinates with close proximity from database

Tags: c#, sql, google-maps-api-3, gps

I have a table containing large sets of latitude and longitude values in the form of -26.0346511492626 and 28.0677509307861. A user can select his address from a google map and I have to determine if the selected address is within 50km of any of the already captured GPS coordinates.

Because the table contains a large set of values I have to avoid iterating through all of the existing GPS coordinates to calculate the distance. Is there any way to select only coordinates that is within a close proximity from the selected address? Then I can work with a smaller data set in order to calculate the distance between points.

Comment: Yes, you can query the database with some tolerance value with respect to your/user position. Find out all the GPS with tolerance value added to the userlocation, it will cut down data set as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a particular longitude you should be able to determine the longitude that is 50km north and the longitude that is 50km south (assuming there's no addresses within 50km of the poles). Do the same for latitudes. Search for values that fit within both of these ranges. Find the smallest distance within this subset. Obviously some of the points within the bounds may still be up to sqrt(50*50*2)km away so you still have to compare against that rather than just taking the minimum.